# Sample code to transfer funds using bcoin

Tags: bcoin

I am new to bitcoin world. I wanted to get a sample code to transfer bitcoins from one bitcoin account to another using javascript and bcoin. The inputs are sender's private key and address, receiver's address, and may be a change address. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming, not bitcoin specifically.